# TypeError: validator.escape is not a function - (express-validator@6.12.1 package)

Tags: node.js, function, typeerror, xss, express-validator

**Codecademy video:** [link](https://youtu.be/d0pWvLyngHM?t=605)

**Explanation:**

> As part of my `Codecademy Back-End Engineer training`, I have to do a project outside of their platform. The goal of this project is to make sure a node application is protected from common web attacks.

> One challenge I faced was securing the code from `Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks`. To do this, I used a package called `express-validator@6.12.1`. The code uses a function called `validator.escape` which is supposed to protect against any malicious code being inserted into an input form. However, I am getting an error in the console when I try to use it.

**Terminal output :**

```
TypeError: validator.escape is not a function
```

**Here is the code :**

```
const validator = require("express-validator");


app.post("/public_forum", function (request, response) {
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    var comment = validator.escape(request.body.comment);
    var username = request.session.username;
    if (comment) {
      db.all(
        `INSERT INTO public_forum (username,message) VALUES ('${username}','${comment}')`,
        (err, rows) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
      db.all(`SELECT username,message FROM public_forum`, (err, rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        console.log(err);
        response.render("forum", { rows });
      });
    } else {
      db.all(`SELECT username,message FROM public_forum`, (err, rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        console.log(err);
        response.render("forum", { rows });
      });
    }
    comment = "";
  } else {
    response.redirect("/");
  }
  comment = "";
  //response.end();
});
```

In the video of `Codecademy`, the guy uses this function.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');

app.post('/public_forum', async function (request, response) {
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    await check('comment').trim().escape().run(req);
    const validationResult = await validationResult(req);
    if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
      // Good to go...
      const { comment } = req.body;
    }
    ...
```

[Link](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/migration-v5-to-v6/#sample-code-using-v6) to official docs

Answer (score 1):

try importing 'validator' instead of 'express-validator.' had the same issue and this worked for me. still don't fully understand the difference between the two since codecademy does a bad job explaining and even confuses them in their own project.

edit: oh and you'll have to install validator first!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code. I tried to add both a malicious and safe comment, but I got an error message on my browser that said, "Port 4000 Not Found." Every time I run the code, it kills the port. So I have implemented another code that works well based on what you sent me.

```
// This code defines a post request handler for the "/public_forum" endpoint.
app.post('/public_forum', async function (request, response) {
  // Check if the user is logged in by checking the session data.
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    // Trim and escape the incoming comment.
    await check('comment').trim().escape().run(request);
    // Get the validation result of the incoming comment.
    const errors = validationResult(request);
    // If the validation result contains errors, return a 400 status with the errors in a JSON format.
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return response.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    // Get the comment from the request body.
    const { comment } = request.body;
    // If a valid comment exists, insert it into the "public_forum" database table.
    if (comment) {
      db.run(
        `INSERT INTO public_forum (username,message) VALUES (?,?)`, [request.session.username, comment],
        (err) => {
          // If an error occurs while inserting the comment, log the error.
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }
      );
    }
    // Select all the rows from the "public_forum" table.
    db.all(`SELECT username,message FROM public_forum`, (err, rows) => {
      // If an error occurs while selecting the rows, log the error.
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      // Log the selected rows.
      console.log(rows);
      // Render the "forum" template, passing in the selected rows as a parameter.
      response.render("forum", { rows });
    });
  } else {
    // If the user is not logged in, redirect them to the homepage.
    response.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

Comment: It's better to remove execessive comments to make the code more readable. The code should be self-documenting!